# Use GDAL TOOLS to change a JPEG plate-carree to a proper GeoTIFF using gdal_translate

Tags: geotiff-tiff, extents, gdal-translate

I am trying to use GDAL TOOLS to change a JPEG plate-carree to a proper GeoTIFF using gdal_translate.

My input JPEG image is a full map of the Earth in plate-carree projection. I want to output this as a GeoTIFF that I can "gdal_merge.py" other GeoTIFFs to.

What is the proper syntax to change a JPEG full equirectangular projection image to GeoTIFF format extents = -180 to +180 +90 to -90 ?

I have tried various combinations of -te and -a_ullr that produce syntax errors or nonsense extents. The gdal_translate command seems to want metres instead of geographic coordinates (180-EW,90-NS ). What have I overlooked?

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr [ -180 -90 +180 +90 ]  -te [-180 -90 +180 +90 ] -a_srs "+proj=eqc +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-0" plate-carree.jpg plate-carree.tif

gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr  -180 -90 +180 +90  -te -180 -90 +180 +90  -a_srs "+proj=eqc +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-0" plate-carree.jpg plate-carree.tif

gdal_translate -of Gtiff  -te -180 -90 +180 +90  -a_srs "+proj=eqc +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-0" plate-carree.jpg plate-carree.tif

gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr  -180 -90 +180 +90    -a_srs "+proj=eqc +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-0" plate-carree.jpg plate-carree.tif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last command is close to correct. The three first ones use an unsupported `-te` parameter that you have probably captured from gdalwarp. The main issue anyway is that you are defining the corner coordinates in wrong units for the equidistant cylindical. Another error in all the commands is that you have not noticed that the latitude coordinate is growing from south to north so the upper left corner has the biggest value for latitude/northing.

The definition of Equidistant cylindrical is at https://epsg.org/crs_4087/WGS-84-World-Equidistant-Cylindrical.html? See the remarks:

> Origin is at intersection of equator and Greenwich meridian. Note:
> this is not the same as plotting unrectified graticule coordinates on
> a computer display using the so-called pseudo Plate Carrée method:
> here the grid units are metres.

If you would like to assign the extent to the image then you must give the extent as meters. Unfortunately the EPSG database does not show those metric extremes.

In the GIS world EPSG:4326 is used to mean that so-called pseudo Plate Carrée.

If the source image is like this

[image]

I would do the job in the steps:

- assign the corner coordinates and EPSG:4326 coordinate system

`gdal_translate -a_ullr  -180 +90 +180 -90 -a_srs epsg:4326 input.tif pseudo_plate_carree.tif`

- warp the pseudo Plate Carrée into Equidistant Cylindrical with gdalwarp

`gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4087 pseudo_plate_carree.tif equidistant_cylindrical.tif`

The gdalwarp command is just a convenient way to change the corner coordinates from degrees inte metres. The final image seems to have now these corner coordinates:

```
Upper Left  (-20037508.343,10018754.171)
Lower Right (20037508.343,-10018754.171)
```

A single-command solution would be then

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -20037508.343 10018754.171 20037508.343 -10018754.171 -a_srs epsg:4087 input.tif plate_carree.tif
```

However, it is not necessary to use the metric EPSG:4087 at all. GDAL and other GIS programs can pretty well deal with the pseudo version EPSG:4326.